# how to plot 2 or more maesurements(csv) with different time axis into one figure with pandas and plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am doing measurements of a device. I sample different values, like temperatures at different times.
Now I like to visualize my data as curves via plotly and pandas.

I am looking for advice how to do this.

To give an example and for simplicity I have 2 data sets stored in 2 seperate csv files, with identical headers. Like:
ds1.csv

```
                     timestamp  value
2021-09-09 16:47:36.231446    355
2021-09-09 16:47:41.208629    355
```

ds2.csv

```
                     timestamp  value
2021-09-09 16:47:36.236132     30
2021-09-09 16:47:46.235707     30
2021-09-09 16:47:56.240340     30
```

The timestamps of the values are not the same, but they are referring to the same clock.

So I like to draw ds1 and ds2 into the same figure with plotly.

```
fig1 = plotly.express.line(ds1, x = 'timestamp', y = 'value', title='Temp1')
fig2 = plotly.express.line(ds2, x = 'timestamp', y = 'value', title='Temp2')
?fig = fig1 and fig2?
fig.show()
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the files as pandas dataframes. It will be easier to plot two graphs on the same plot if you use plotly graph objects `go.Bar or go.Scatter`. You can make the xaxis(timestamps) ticks vary linearly by giving a range and `dticks` parameter.

The below example shows a simple scatter plot which contains two figures plotted on same graph.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"X":np.linspace(0,30,10), "Y":np.random.rand(10)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":np.linspace(0,40,10), "B":np.random.rand(10)})

# plotting the graphs...


def scatter_chart(x, y, color, name):

   trace = go.Scatter(
         x=x.values,
         y=y.values,
         name=name,

         marker=dict(
                color=color,
                line=dict(
                color=color,
                width=1)
              ),
          )
  return trace
# for loop could be used
trace1 = scatter_chart(df2["A"], df2["B"], 'rgb(128, 0, 128)', "df2")
trace2 = scatter_chart(df1["X"], df1["Y"], 'rgba(50, 171, 96, 0.6)', "df1")
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1,cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.5)
fig.add_trace(trace1)
fig.add_trace(trace2)

fig.update_layout(
   title="df2 and df1 plot",
   height=600, 
   width=600, 
  # annotations=annotations, 
  xaxis=dict(tickangle=-45),
  legend=dict(x=0.029, y=1.038, font_size=10),
  margin=dict(l=100, r=20, t=70, b=70),
  paper_bgcolor='rgb(248, 248, 255)',
  plot_bgcolor='rgb(248, 248, 255)',)

# xaxis could be customized further
fig['layout']['xaxis'].update(title='', range=[0, 500], dtick=50, autorange=False)
py.iplot(fig, filename='pageviews_plots_4')
```

Please run the code and see..hope you get the idea.